# Math library on BeagleBone Black

Tags: math, beagleboneblack

I would like on the BeagleBone Black calculate the trigonometric functions, but does not know how to add the appropriate library and the new functions are not recognized in javascript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVK1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.atan` and `Math.PI`. And care about what is connected by parentheses. Something like

```
angle = Math.atan(state/state2) * 180/Math.PI;
```

or even

```
angle = Math.atan2(state,state2) * 180/Math.PI;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
Maybe you know how to round a number in javascript? I try Math.round() but this not working

Comment: That depends: Do you want to do further computations with the rounded number or is the rounding for display only? `a.toFixed(2)` produces a string with 2 decimal places from the number variable `a`.